# How can I get full names for mfc_ functions with IDA Pro?

Tags: mfc, ida

Almost all the time when I use IDA Pro I see standard library functions with prefix mfc_ . Is there any way how I can get full names for these functions?
Something like mfc140u_4656 for vswprintf ?

Comment: What makes you assume that `mfc140u_4656` weren't the full name?

Comment: Yeah, right :) 
Basically, this is full name for dll exported function. But my question is more about how can i get more obvious names for mfc_ functions(by this suffix number _4656) like memory allocations or string comparison, etc. It's not a big deal to come up with function purpose, just want to make pseudocode more readable

Comment: Get the public debug symbols from Microsoft's symbol server.